# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::getFillable() in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I have used multi authentication in laravel 7 but when I want to login and press submit then the error

> Bad Method Call Exception Call to undefined method App\User::get Fillable is appear.

Comment: where you want to redirect yourself after login show controller function in your code for more understanding

Comment: Adding the code from the model could make it easier to help... did you extend Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model in your App\User model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you extends  Authenticatable class to your auth controller? If not try it.